# Integrate Digest Authentication in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, digest-authentication

I want to integrate digest authentication in my objective c code. 
I am using NSURLSessionDataTask.
In first webservice call i fetch the nonce value and then in next call i set the header of the same webservice.

```
NSDictionary *payload;
    payload = @{
                @"Username"  : @"",
                @"Password"  : @"",
                };
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:10.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:payload
                                                   options:0 error:&error];
    request.HTTPBody = data;

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                    if (error) {
                                                        NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                    } else {
                                                        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

                                                        NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);
                                                        NSDictionary* dictHeaders = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];

                                                         NSLog(@"%@",[dictHeaders objectForKey:@"Www-Authenticate"]);

                                                        [self callWSAfterAuthentication:[dictHeaders objectForKey:@"Www-Authenticate"]];
                                                    }
                                                }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what do you have problems with exactly? This is not a free code writing service.

Comment: @mag_zbc i have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You have not said in your question what exact problems you have. Assuming the authentication simply does not work:

Add a `NSURLSessionDelegate` to your `NSURLSession` and handle the authentication in the `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` delegate method. Check for `NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPDigest` and respond accordingly. (You can find info on how to implement this)